# COM Local Server (Out of process) w/ Python

Tags: python, com

I have a question related to Python and COM.

I have been given a program which is an out-of-process COM local server (it is an .EXE). It is designed to be a Singleton, so there is always only one instance running on a machine. It is designed to support multiple clients. My question is how do I create a Python client to work with the it.

I have limited experience with COM in general, and my situation specifically appears to be rare. Basically, the interface methods are defined, and how to implement the interface is loosely defined in a C++ context. However, I am having trouble doing the same thing in Python.

I am using win32com and pythoncom, but the documentation for both is rather vague and I cannot figure out how to implement this. I've also tried using the COM Makepy utility in PythonWin, but I do not know what to do with the file it generates.

I apologize if my question is too vague, as this is my first time using stack overflow. Most other questions related to Python and COM almost touch on my topic, but I still need some more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your question is a little vague. It sounds like your problem is just the "talking to COM" side of things - ie. not the singleton server stuff.  I managed to work this out from the Win23com docs, and I think a chapter in a book (which I've since passed on - but I think it was an O'Reilly learning python type book).

Anyway, I did write anarticle on calling MapPoint from Python using win32com, here:

http://www.mapping-tools.com/howto/programming/using-python-with-mappoint/

It might be possible to crib from this and get something working?
Perhaps try something with a known COM interface where examples exist, first. Eg. one of the Office products or MapPoint (if you have it available).